# Android Canvas - Callbacks to draw a dot and reposition it based on GPS movement

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

I am new to android and i've just been looking into the canvas API. I currently have an activity class called "MyMap" and a ViewClass called "MapView" (which extends view).

The MyMap activity sets the content view to MapView and inside MapView I am creating a canvas with a bitmap image of a Map and I am then drawing a circle on the map based on the current GPS coordinates of the mobile. I want to know how do I perform some callback to the draw() method whenever the gps coordinates change? also will this code go in MyMap activity or in the MapView?

Comment: Are you asking how to get GPS updates, or how to do something once you get a GPS update?  Also a little confused on why you would be creating a canvas to put a map ontop of a mapview? Mapview is for google maps and does all the map drawing for you.

Comment: i'm not using googlemaps. I want to load a bitmap image of a map tile. I then want to plot a you-are-here marker on that map image. Whenever the mobile moves and changes gps coordinates, I then want the map to update the you-are-here marker and move in relation to the phones location

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first setup a gps listener and respond to that, you can find information about that here [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

It would look something like this. Keep in mind that GPS sucks battery, there are ways to do this better but here is the meat of it, more or less

Once you have that setup just do what you need to do in the onLocationChanged listener

**CODE SNIPPET - NOT COMPLETE**

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;

public class gps extends Activity  {

    private LocationManager locManager = null; 

        public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
           super.onCreate(state);

           locManager = (LocationManager)App.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                  // DO SOMETHING HERE with the updated location information to change your map

            }
        }

        public onResume() {
             startGPS(1000,1); // Every second or when we move 1 meter
        }

        public onPause() {
             stopGPS(); 
        }

        private boolean startGPS(long interval, float meterTrigger)
    {

        if (!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            return false; 



                            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,interval,meterTrigger,onLocationChange);



                return true;
        }

        public void stopGPS() {
       locManager.removeUpdates(onLocationChange); 
    }
```

**Painting the circle** - you will need to determine the positioning and radius

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float r = 0; 

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); // You can cache this higher up and reuse it 
    paint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);  
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, paint);
}
```

Comment: thanks. Are there any good tutorials on drawing on an image. Essentially i am just drawing on an image every time the gps of the phone changes..

Comment: @cptham are you wanting to draw (as in draw a circle etc.) or are you wanting to overlay one bitmap on top of the other?

Comment: i want to draw a circle which represents the users location. Saw literally draw a circle on a bitmap image (which happens to be a map)

Comment: @cptham take a look at the draw circle added to original answer, if onDraw doesnt work try dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) instead.

Comment: I understand drawing a circle on a bitmap image. I understand the code to get your gps location and check for changes. I'm just unsure on how you bridge the two between the Activity class and your custom View class (where the canvas and drawCircle method is)

Comment: The GPS goes in the activity, then when you get an location update call a public method that you need to add in the MapView to draw the circle such as drawLocation(Location L) and in that method store the location and then invalidate the view.